# How to turn javascript function to json

Tags: javascript, json, handsontable

I am  working with handsontable and a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/cb920ear/ . In this there is the following js function:

```
  function getCarData() {
    return [
      {car: "Mercedes A 160", year: 2006, available: true, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      {car: "Citroen C4 Coupe", year: 2008, available: false, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      {car: "Audi A4 Avant", year: 2011, available: true, comesInBlack: 'no'},
      {car: "Opel Astra", year: 2004, available: false, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      {car: "BMW 320i Coupe", year: 2011, available: false, comesInBlack: 'no'}
    ];
  }
```

What is this data structure is this? I can see its not a 2d array or json. Is there an easy way to change it to json which I will need to receive from a server to load the handsontable?

Comment: Looks exactly like a 2D array to me, containing objects ?

Comment: Other than `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: What *exactly* do you need to do with this array?  What does `handsontable` expect?  I don't see any need to convert this to a JSON string.  You just to convert it to a format that `handsontable` can use, which I assume is an array or an object, not a JSON string.

Comment: Sorry, I went back and looked again, and I realize that I misread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329092/multi-dimensional-associative-arrays-in-javascript and it is indeed a  2D array or array of objects

Comment: Rocket, I want to change the example data in getCarData() to json so that I can simulate a db backend that produces json for consumption by handsontable.

Comment: You want to "simulate a db backend" with JavaScript?  I'm a little confused here.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear. I have a php backend that produces a json representation of a db table. I want to use a frontend view with handsontable to display this.

Comment: try `JSON.stringify(getCarData())` then push the result to your backend

Comment: Your fiddle has an error when you click the button: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

Comment: It returns an object with an array. Perhaps a simple example: alert(getCarData()[2].car); which alerts "Audi A4 Avant" as in this fiddle will help you understand? http://jsfiddle.net/h6nh1gvw/

Comment: Mark, thanks for the fiddle, that helps. What does "object with an array" mean? array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn a function into json do

```
JSON.stringify(getCarData, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return value.toString();
  }
  return value;
});
```

returned `""function getCarData() {\n    return [\n      {car: \"Mercedes A 160\", year: 2006, available: true, comesInBlack: 'yes'},\n      {car: \"Citroen C4 Coupe\", year: 2008, available: false, comesInBlack: 'yes'},\n      {car: \"Audi A4 Avant\", year: 2011, available: true, comesInBlack: 'no'},\n      {car: \"Opel Astra\", year: 2004, available: false, comesInBlack: 'yes'},\n      {car: \"BMW 320i Coupe\", year: 2011, available: false, comesInBlack: 'no'}\n    ];\n  }""` to me. See http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/07/json-serialize-and-deserialize.html

Comment: Shouldn't that just be `JSON.stringify(getCarData())`?  Why are you trying to convert the *function* itself into JSON?  He wants to manipulate the *return value* of that function.

Comment: Also, it's *not* an array of "json objects".  It's an array of [JavaScript] objects.  JSON is a *string representation* of data; if it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: err the question title is 'How to turn javascript function to json' so I showed how to turn his function into a json string.

Comment: Also `JSON.stringify(<function>)` will return undefined. Hence the need for the callback provided above.

Comment: Ah I see you passed the result of executing the function into JSON.stringify. This would stringify the result but not serialize the function. Depends on what you want really.

Comment: Pretty sure he want's the result of the function call, not the function itself.  P.S. Not many people here seem to know how to write good question titles.

Comment: Rocket is correct in what I meant, Harry but I'm accepting your answer because you answered the question I actually asked.