# Creating Javascript multidimensional associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is how a multidimensional associative array (I mean object, as multidimensional associative array is not present in JavaScript) is defined generally in JavaScript,

```
var array = {};
array['fruit'] = {};
array['fruit']['citrus'] = ['lemon', 'orange'];
```

In other languages like PHP, it can be defined as,

```
$array['fruit']['citrus'] = ['lemon', 'orange'];
```

Is it possible to create a multidimensional associative array in JavaScript like this?

Comment: JSON is just a subset of JavaScript so...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-dimensional associative arrays in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329092/multi-dimensional-associative-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can define it in one go like this:

```
var array = {
    fruit: {
       citrus: ['Lemon', 'Orange']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = {
    fruit: {
        citrus: ['Lemon', 'Orange']
    }
};

var fruits = array["fruit"];
>>> {"citrus": ["Lemon", "Orange"]}

var citrus_fruits = fruits["citrus"];
>>> ["Lemon", "Orange"]

var orange = citrus_fruits[1];
>>> "Orange"
```

Also have a look at [JSON](http://json.org/) - JavaScript Object Notation.