# Adding objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I am very new to JavaScript and need some guidance. I am trying to build a reference for people in a club. I started by creating an array like so:

```
var People = ['Adam', 'Bruce', 'Steve']
```

But now I want to add characteristics to Adam, for instance height, weight, age, etc.

I want to be able to access information regarding people in my array by something like:

```
alert(People.Adam.height);
```

How would I structure it so that objects in my array has unique characteristics?

Comment: Looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329092/multi-dimensional-associative-arrays-in-javascript)?

Comment: change your People array to a People object, and then add the properties  you want (name, height, weight, age, etc.) to the new People object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently adding strings into your array, not objects. You need to make your people into objects.

```
var adam = {
    name: 'Adam',
    height: 6.0
}
```

To retrieve Adam's height now, you'd call `adam.height`. So if you had an array, `People`, with adam (and others) inside, here's how you could do it:

```
var people = [adam]
alert(people[0].height)
// Alerts 6
```

**Edit**: alternatively, if you'd like to access Adam by name, you could make `people` an object instead of an array:

```
var people = {'adam' : adam}
alert(people.adam.height)
// Alerts 6
```

Comment: The only problem here is that OP wants to be able to access Adam by name `people.adam.height`. Here, you would need to know where adam was in the array. Of course you could loop through it and find the object with the right name, but I would suggest using an associative array instead.

Comment: @Pushkin I've added your suggestion, please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
var people = [],
    adam = {
        height: 200,
        weight: 200,
        age: 20
    }; 

people.push(adam);

console.log(people[0].height); // 200
```

or use object instead of array:

```
var people = {},
    adam = {
        height: 200,
        weight: 200,
        age: 20
    };

people.adam = adam;

console.log(people.adam.height); // 200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object, so you can access any nested property of that object:

```
var People = {
  Adam: {
    height: '187',
    age: '22',
    favorite_color: 'orange'
 },
 Paul: {
   height: '156',
   age: '38',
   favorite_color: 'blue'
 }, 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an object that have name of the people as key and the value for each key would be details for the person in form of an object. It could be something like

```
var People = {
    "Adam" : {
          "height" : "someValue",
         "anotherParam" : "someOtherValue"
    },
    "Bruce" : {
         "height" : "someValue",
         "anotherParam" : "someOtherValue"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). It might look like this:

```
class Person {
  constructor(height, weight, birth_year) {
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.birth_year = birth_year;
  }
}
```