# Get array item by multiple keys

Tags: typescript

I need to make a simple generic filter function that makes a verification on javascript event 'change' a search.

I have the following Json:

```
{
    "name": "Ramsey Cummings",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 12.5,
    "address": {
        "state": {
            "post": "20042",
            "name": "South Carolina"
        },
        "city": "Glendale"
    }
}
```

How do i make a generic approach to get all leafs searched in my object?

I added a user mapping that i will pass to my function, example:

```
this.filterDataMap = [
  {
    key: 'address', value: 'state.name'
  }
]
```

My filter function looks as follows:

```
filterTable(array, value) {
let hash = [];
let objectProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array[0]);

$.grep(array, (item, i) => {
  let isValidItem = false;
  objectProperties.forEach(element => {
    let mapElementArray = $.grep(this.filterDataMap, i => i.key === element);
    if (mapElementArray.length > 0) {
      debugger;
      let mapperValue = ''.concat(element, '.', mapElementArray[0].value);
      if (item[mapperValue] !== undefined &&
        item[mapperValue].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1 || !value)
        isValidItem = true;
    }
    else if (item[element] !== undefined && item[element].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1 || !value)
      isValidItem = true;
  });
  if (isValidItem)
    hash.push(item);
})

return hash;
```

}

I found in a different post here that is should be possible to concatenate my object properties like item['address.state.name'] but when i do it i get the undefined result.

Comment: This is the post i'm referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329092/multi-dimensional-associative-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I found this for my situation
https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path

My updated code looks like this now

```
filterTable(array, value) {
let hash = [];
let objectProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array[0]);

$.grep(array, (item, i) => {
  let isValidItem = false;
  objectProperties.forEach(element => {
    let mapElementArray = $.grep(this.filterDataMap, i => i.key === element);
    if (mapElementArray.length > 0) {
      var objectPath = require("object-path");
      let mapperValue = ''.concat(element, '.', mapElementArray[0].value);
      if (objectPath.get(item, mapperValue) !== undefined &&
      objectPath.get(item, mapperValue).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1 || !value)
        isValidItem = true;
    }
    else if (item[element] !== undefined && item[element].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1 || !value)
      isValidItem = true;
  });
  if (isValidItem)
    hash.push(item);
})

return hash;
```

}